# how to avoid circular import of models in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-3.0

I have created two apps in django:
1.polls
2.result

The code in polls.models

```
from django.db import models
from result.models import QuestionToAsk

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

 
class Choice(models.Model):
    question_to_ask = models.ForeignKey(QuestionToAsk, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    #note:this is just an example to illustrate the problem i am facing.
```

The code in result.models

```
from django.db import models
from polls.models import Question

# Create your models here.
class QuestionToAsk(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class ChoiceToMake(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_to_ask = models.ForeignKey(QuestionToAsk, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    #note:this is just an example to illustrate the problem i am facing.
```

When i run :

> python manage.py makemigrations

It throws and error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Question'

I have got to know, the error is because of the circular import. I want to know, what is the other way to avoid circular import in models.

I want to make foreign key in both the app's models.

Comment: Importing entirely `polls.models` and `results.models`, not just one definition, seems to work.

Comment: It is not working for me !!

Comment: Maybe you can show where the error happens in `manage.py`.